# How to check if the current user has the permission to create a database view in MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: php, mariadb

Is the function `can_create_view()` below sufficient to check if the current user has the permission to create a view on a certain MySQL/MariaDB database?

The function checks if the grant contains the phrase "CREATE VIEW" and also checks if it specifies the database name with a clause like `ON database_name.*` or `ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*`.

```
 function can_create_view($database_name, $username, $password) {
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database_name);
        $result = $conn->query("SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            $grant = $row[0];
            if (strpos($grant, "CREATE VIEW") !== false && strpos($grant, "ON `$database_name`.*") !== false && strpos($grant, "ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*") !== false) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

PS:  information_schema.user_privileges doesn't return the "CREATE VIEW" grants. All I see is PRIVILEGE_TYPE: USAGE but the user has the permission to create views.

Comment: Hey, it reads like a question and answer in one... you should be able to just try it out? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Question is, if the function is sufficient or if SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER; could output other variations of "CREATE VIEW", "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `$database_name`.*". I edited the post and added "ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.*"

Comment: ok, i didnt downvote btw. maybe refer to here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create i see that it might get difficult, another option could be to try and catch an attempt to just create a database (dont forget to remove it on success)

Comment: You might get a better answer to this on [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). There is also a generic `CREATE` but the docs say it just allows "Databases, tables, or indexes", so I don't think it can create a view then

Comment: information_schema.user_privileges. Always use information_schema database instead of this archaic stuff

Comment: @YourCommonSense: information_schema.user_privileges doesn't return the "CREATE VIEW" grants. All I see is PRIVILEGE_TYPE: USAGE but the user has the permission to create views.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the right user? Did you try to run select * from information_schema.user_privileges in mysql console and see the full output?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Yes I did and I don't get the same detail as with SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on MariaDB 10.5, only `USAGE` appears when querying `information_schema.user_privileges`, and these users are created with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES...`

Comment: Looks like `information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` is the one that you want to query. To your main question about if those privileges are enough, I unfortunately don't know.

Comment: @ChrisHaas This doesn't seem to be a reliable way. On one of my databases no rows are returned when running that query.

Comment: Hmmm... all of my users on this server (internal dev) are created with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES...` and they're all showing properly. I'm on MariaDB, too. Maybe this is a version thing. The last line on [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-schema-privileges-table.html) warns that `SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` and `SHOW GRANTS` aren't equivalent, so you might be safer going down your original path.

Comment: You clarified in a comment that you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. Please don't tag your question MySQL if you are using MariaDB. These are two different products, and they are becoming more and more incompatible as years go on. Answers for one will not necessarily work for the other, so you should be clear which one you're using.

Comment: @BillKarwin that doesn't mean that the function should work for both MariaDB and MySQL. That's why I also tagged it with MariaDB later.

Answer (score -1):

As @YourCommonSense commented,

You can check it like this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
     information_schema.`USER_PRIVILEGES`
WHERE
    `GRANTEE` LIKE CONCAT(
        '%',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(), '@', 1),
        '%')
```

Sample result from my db

[image]

```
require 'Config.php';

$result     = $conn->query("
SELECT
    *
FROM
    information_schema.`USER_PRIVILEGES`
WHERE
    `GRANTEE` LIKE CONCAT(
        '%',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(), '@', 1),
        '%') 
  ");
$num_rows   = $result->num_rows;
$array = array();   
if ($num_rows  > 0) {       
                    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $array[] = $row;
    }
 }
echo json_encode($array);
```

And Result is

[image]

Comment: I run the query but all I see is "MySQL returned an empty result". On another db, I get a similar output like you. That means it's not a reliable way to get the grants.

Comment: Updated the answer..  information_schema.`USER_PRIVILEGES`

Comment: please try again.

Comment: My first test was with information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES, 
In the PIVILEGE_TYPE column all I see is USAGE when running SELECT * FROM information_schema.`USER_PRIVILEGES`

Comment: Whats your db ? mysql or mariadb and version ?

Comment: 10.4.22-MariaDB. Strange thing is that on one db I get the desired output and on 3 others I don't

Comment: You mean to say you have 4 db servers OR you have 4 db in same server ?

Comment: I have 4 db servers, I just get an output on localhost

Comment: You may want to test it on the onecompiler.com/mysql website. It's possible to create a table and then a view from it but your query also returns USAGE in the PRIVILEGE_TYPE column

Comment: I am able to see here https://dbfiddle.uk/bzolfnhA

Comment: Exactly, in some configurations you get that output and sometimes you don't. That's why information_schema.`USER_PRIVILEGES` is not reliable.

Comment: Can you show the one which is not woking for you ?

Comment: The one on the onecompiler.com/mysql website. Create a table + view there, add some data and run your sql.

Comment: Cannot do homework :(

Comment: It's not homework. I already tested it there. In this case, you will not be able to reproduce it...
I merely referred to a page where you can test that your check does not always work reliably.